# SCSS Style Encapsulation per Component with Vite in a Component Library

Tags: reactjs, sass, vite

I have a problem with SCSS encapsulation per component. I'm building a component library and, for example, I have an Alert.jsx component and an Alert.scss file. The SCSS file is imported in the Alert.jsx file, and through Vite, I want my styles to be per component rather than compiled as a whole. Does anyone have a solution for this? So that each component exported from my component library through Vite and used within another application has style encapsulation?

My structure src/components/Alert(Alert.jsx, Alert.scss)

my vite config

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { libInjectCss } from 'vite-plugin-lib-inject-css';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react(), libInjectCss()],
    build: {
        outDir: 'lib',
        cssCodeSplit: true,
        lib: {
            entry: 'src/index.js',
            name: 'common-ui',
            formats: ['es'],
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
            input: {
                components: 'src/components/index.js',
            },
            output: {
                entryFileNames: `[name]/index.js`,
                chunkFileNames: `[name]/[hash]/index.js`,
                assetFileNames: `[name]/[hash]/[name].[ext]`,
                inlineDynamicImports: false,
            },
        },
    },
});
```